# remix account get private key

Tags: ethereum, contract, remix

I want to sign message in remix, interacting with ethereum contract.

But I can't find private key.

[image]

Comment: You can't get private key on Remix. There is only one way to test with private key, the solution is use web3 provider and use your private key but it's only for test code.

Comment: here you can find the list of private keys of remix accounts.
[https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78040/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-private-key-of-test-account-in-remix-javascript-vm](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78040/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-private-key-of-test-account-in-remix-javascript-vm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the private key from the embedded accounts in the "JavaScript VM" environment in Remix. What you need to do is download and run [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) and switch the environment over to "Web3 Provider".

When you start Ganache, you'll see a summary of accounts and private keys like the following:

> Available Accounts
>   ================== (0) 0x9a6d82ef3912d5ab60473124bccd2f2a640769d7 (1) 0x65463bf6268e5cc409b6501ec846487b935a1446 (2)
>   0xb98e575977160c29301f8f9444710048c5bb9a1c (3)
>   0x1655e4b2e19d5934d9336f8b1dd351e14ce466ba (4)
>   0x40ade79c474c47991fcb1b62308a4e755864e24d (5)
>   0x4888ba85dd44fd3416a0788ab9bde63290a6c8e2
>
> Private Keys
>   ================== (0) 70f1384b24df3d2cdaca7974552ec28f055812ca5e4da7a0ccd0ac0f8a4a9b00 (1)
>   ad0352cfc09aa0128db4e135fcea276523c400163dcc762a11ecba29d5f0a34a (2)
>   85fa10d6fc72b1b86e0b876167507297b21aae5f4bcd7d518c11c837c6229b3f (3)
>   c49f807bc5e8d332df558f77fdd48f10b112a8f2c2ce50a32d09def7d7d1ef16 (4)
>   d38e9c788f4c6d09f0da1ff8140bf8600aacca559ba3b82ff7cd76e450f3c5f4 (5)
>   d8acd90819cee0299336324ff56b87524c165e8ad7fd6d150c518f89754059e3

Use one of those private keys to sign your transaction.

The list of accounts and private keys change after every restart. If you need to have them persist, start Ganache with the `--accounts` option

```
ganache-cli --account "0x70f1384b24df3d2cdaca7974552ec28f055812ca5e4da7a0ccd0ac0f8a4a9b00,300000000000000000000" --account "0xad0352cfc09aa0128db4e135fcea276523c400163dcc762a11ecba29d5f0a34a,300000000000000000000"
```